# Creating a dendrogram with the results from the results the multipatt function in the indicspecies package

Tags: r

I am getting familiar with the `multipatt` function in `indicspecies` package. Thus far I only see `summary` being used to give a breakdown of the results. However I would like a dendrogram, ideally with the names of the species which are more 'indicative' of my given community location.

example from package file:

```
library(indicspecies)
 library(stats)
data(wetland) ## Loads species data
wetkm = kmeans(wetland, centers=3) ## Creates three clusters using kmeans
## Runs the combination analysis using IndVal.g as statistic
wetpt = multipatt(wetland, wetkm$cluster, control = how(nperm=999))
## Lists those species with significant association to one combination
summary(wetpt)
```

`wetpt` gives the raw results but I am not sure how to proceed to get a cluster plot out of this result. Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: what's the `how` given to control? is it a custom function?

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31083/how-to-produce-a-pretty-plot-of-the-results-of-k-means-cluster-analysis

Comment: My apologies, I meant a dendrogram. But appreciate the link.

Comment: After some googling, packages `rpart` and/or `tree` might be useful.